# Managing fields visibility

Tags: users, flags

I have 2 user roles in my Drupal 7 site 'A' and 'B' respectively:

Users of role `A` can create and publish content.

Users of role `B` can not create content but they can view all published content.

Content in my case is an invitation to some event (ie "Who wants to play football on Friday?")

`B` users can click the button under each invitation to join event. For this I used `Flags` and `Rules`. `A` users can see who flagged their content.

But `A` users have to review potential participants profiles and confirm their participation. In user profile I have created button filed with following permissions
[image: Field is available only on <code>B</code> users page and visible only to <code>a</code> users]

But this field is displayed on each `B` user profile page whatever he flagged content or not. How can I make this field visible to `A` users only when `B` user falgs the content?

Comment: is the goal to show all B users who have requested participation on each node to users of A, or (and) on show the profile of B showing all participation requests for that user?

Comment: Currently `A` users can see all potential participants (I used node flag for that). Now I want to implement mechanism that allows `A` user confirm participation. Certainly `A` user wants to review a profile before confirmation, therefore I put `confirm` button on `B` user profile page. I will appreciate if you suggest better idea on how to implement that.